# Webconfig file not formed correclty

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

On my live box I am getting an error that the connection string is malformerd but when i try it on my dev box it is fine.

> ```
> <add name="aperturenetEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ApertureModel.csdl|res://*/ApertureModel.ssdl|res://*/ApertureModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=APR-AZ-DB01;initial catalog=aperturenet;user id=aperturenet;password=dw13£sowwoq;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
> <add name="aperturenetSql" connectionString="Data Source=APR-AZ-DB01;database=aperturenet;User ID=username;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
> ```

They are both .net 4.5 boxes with no difference in sql version of the driver but yet i get malformed elements when running the application any idea?.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36836550/edit) to include the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<add name="aperturenetEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ApertureModel.csdl|res://*/ApertureModel.ssdl|res://*/ApertureModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=APR-AZ-DB01;initial catalog=aperturenet;user id=aperturenet;password=dw13£sowwoq;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

try this,
i have changed Application Name to App in your connection string.